# JavaScript - Dates are not equal

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

No clue why I'm getting two different dates for a code below

```
        var aDate = '12/31/2014';
        var bDate = new Date(aDate);
        var cDate = bDate.setMonth(bDate.getMonth() + 3);
        var calDate = new Date(cDate);
        var yc = calDate.getFullYear(), mc = calDate.getMonth(), dc = calDate.getDate();
        alert(calDate + ' ' + mc+'/'+dc+'/'+yc);
```

For me mc/dc/yc should be same day as calDate

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5888s54q/)

Comment: You're forgetting that javascript months are zero-based. JS month #2 is real-world month #3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Month is 0-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth):

```
mc = calDate.getMonth()+1
```

Comment: Wow, that is interesting

Comment: OK, found it: 0=January, 1=February etc.